# I have trouble reading a particular array in a JSON feed

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

I use json_decode() to parse a json feed and everything works just fine until I come to the array (media) that keeps digits as key instead of letters. I have tryed everything but all I get is different errors when it comes to this array (media)

The media array contains links to images and I just need the first image in every media array really. But the array can keep random digits in different order for the image links.
But the main problem is that I can't print this key, even if I know the name of it is "10" for example.
My second problem is that I never know the digits of the first image.

I would be very grateful if I can get help with this.

My code:

```
$data = json_decode($json_obj);


foreach($data->events as $event) {

echo $event->eventDateTime.'<br>'; //works
echo $event->eventId.'<br>'; //works
echo $event->title->eventTitleText.'<br>'; //works
echo strtoupper($event->venue->city).'<br>'; //works
echo $event->venue->title.'<br>'; //works
echo $event->ticketing->url.'<br>'; //works

echo $event->media->10.'<br>'; // Does NOT work
}
```

Below is a complete json feed that contains just 1 event.

```
   {
"meta":{
"total":117,
"locale":"en-US",
"page":1,
"rows":1
},
"events":[
{
"-----":"252975",
"modifiedUTC":"2014-08-29T17:23:21",
"locale":"en-US",
"localeAvailable":{
"1":"sv-SE"
},
"title":{
"presentedBy":null,
"headliners":"<a href=\"http:\/\/www....\/artists\/251396\/djurgarden-hockey\">Djurg\u00e5rden Hockey<\/a> - Eisb\u00e4ren Berlin",
"supporting":null,
"supportingText":null,
"tour":"Champions Hockey League",
"eventTitle":"<a href=\"http:\/\/www....\/artists\/251396\/djurgarden-hockey\">Djurg\u00e5rden Hockey<\/a> - Eisb\u00e4ren Berlin",
"eventTitleText":"Djurg\u00e5rden Hockey - Eisb\u00e4ren Berlin"
},
"age":null,
"currency":"SEK",
"currencySymbol":null,
"eventDateTime":"2014-09-05T20:05:00",
"eventDateTimeZone":"Europe\/Stockholm",
"eventDateTimeUTC":"2014-09-05T18:05:00",
"eventDateTimeISO":"2014-09-05T20:05:00+02:00",
"dateOnly":false,
"additionalDates":[
],
"doorDateTime":null,
"doorDateTimeUTC":null,
"announceDateTime":"2014-08-04T10:00:00",
"announceDateTimeTimeZone":"Europe\/Stockholm",
"announceDateTimeUTC":"2014-08-04T08:00:00",
"presaleDateTime":null,
"presaleDateTimeTimeZone":null,
"presaleDateTimeUTC":null,
"presaleEndDateTime":null,
"presaleEndDateTimeTimeZone":null,
"presaleEndDateTimeUTC":null,
"onsaleDateTime":"2014-08-06T09:00:00",
"onsaleDateTimeTimeZone":"Europe\/Stockholm",
"onsaleDateTimeUTC":"2014-08-06T07:00:00",
"ticketing":{
"statusId":1,
"status":"Buy Tickets",
"callToAction":"Get your tickets today!",
"callToActionEnabled":false,
"url":"http:\/\/www....\/events\/252975\/djurgarden-hockey-eisbaren-berlin-tickets",
"eventUrl":"http:\/\/www....\/events\/252975\/djurgarden-hockey-eisbaren-berlin-tickets",
"ticketLinkExists":true
},
"ticketPrice":"120.00 kr - 170.00 kr",
"doorPrice":null,
"bio":null,
"description":null,
"minorCategoryId1":"34",
"minorCategoryId2":null,
"minorCategoryId3":null,
"majorCategoryId1":"3",
"majorCategoryId2":null,
"majorCategoryId3":null,
"venue":{
"venueId":"101916",
"locale":"en-US",
"localeAvailable":{
"1":"en-US",
"2":"sv-SE"
},
"title":"Hovet",
"address_line":"Globentorget 2, Stockholm, Sweden 121 27",
"address":"Globentorget 2",
"city":"Stockholm",
"state":null,
"postalCode":"121 27",
"country":"Sweden",
"url":"http:\/\/www....\/venues\/101916\/hovet-stockholm-tickets",
"urlSlug":"hovet-stockholm-tickets",
"venueUrl":"http:\/\/www.globearenas.se\/archive\/pages\/18711\/hovet.aspx",
"phone1":"0771-31 00 00",
"phone2":null,
"alias":null,
"parking":null,
"boxOffice":null,
"directions":null,
"longitude":"18.0808159",
"latitude":"59.2941674",
"timezone":"Europe\/Stockholm",
"ada":null,
"keywords":[
],
"skinCode":"sga",
"currency":"SEK",
"media":{
"10":{
"media_id":"29254",
"width":318,
"height":187,
"file_name":"http:\/\/........net\/10-08172012-502e82fe803bf.jpeg"
},
"11":{
"media_id":"29256",
"width":238,
"height":140,
"file_name":"http:\/\/........net\/11-08172012-502e82fe8f5a7.jpeg"
},
"14":{
"media_id":"29258",
"width":608,
"height":252,
"file_name":"http:\/\/........net\/14-08172012-502e83abb9512.jpeg"
},
"12":{
"media_id":"29255",
"width":134,
"height":79,
"file_name":"http:\/\/........net\/12-08172012-502e82fe88c58.jpeg"
}
},
"links":[
{
"link_id":976779,
"link_title":null,
"link_type_id":"23",
"link_href":"http:\/\/www.marriott.com\/search\/submitSearch.mi?searchType=InCity&formType=InCity&marriottBrands=BR&destinationAddress.city=Stockholm&destinationAddress.stateProvince=&destinationAddress.country=SE"
}
]
},
"tour":[
],
"promoters":null,
"associations":{
"performerIds":[
"251396"
],
"headliners":[
{
"performerId":"251396",
"locale":"en-US",
"localeAvailable":{
"1":"en-US"
},
"name":"Djurg\u00e5rden Hockey",
"minorCategoryText":"Hockey",
"minorCategoryId":"34",
"minorCategory1Id":"34",
"minorCategory2Id":null,
"minorCategory3Id":null,
"minorCategoryUrl":"http:\/\/www....\/browse\/sports\/hockey",
"majorCategoryText":"Sports",
"major_category_id":"3",
"majorCategory1Id":"3",
"majorCategory2Id":null,
"majorCategory3Id":null,
"majorCategoryUrl":"http:\/\/www....\/browse\/sports",
"keywords":[
"DIF",
"Djurgarden"
],
"bio":null,
"shortBio":null,
"aliases":null,
"url":"http:\/\/www....\/artists\/251396\/djurgarden-hockey-tickets",
"urlSlug":"djurgarden-hockey-tickets",
"media":{
"7":{
"media_id":"149467",
"width":220,
"height":220,
"file_name":"http:\/\/........net\/djurgarden-hockey_11-26-13_7_5294e45990e1f.jpg"
},
"24":{
"media_id":"149463",
"width":322,
"height":322,
"file_name":"http:\/\/........net\/djurgarden-hockey_11-26-13_24_5294e45974caa.jpg"
},
"6":{
"media_id":"149465",
"width":238,
"height":140,
"file_name":"http:\/\/........net\/djurgarden-hockey_11-26-13_6_5294e459867f5.jpg"
},
"5":{
"media_id":"149466",
"width":318,
"height":187,
"file_name":"http:\/\/........net\/djurgarden-hockey_11-26-13_5_5294e4598bec3.jpg"
},
"9":{
"media_id":"149464",
"width":134,
"height":79,
"file_name":"http:\/\/........net\/djurgarden-hockey_11-26-13_9_5294e45981552.jpg"
}
},
"events":[
],
"links":[
{
"link_id":976320,
"link_title":null,
"link_type_id":"13",
"link_href":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/difhockeyse"
},
{
"link_id":976321,
"link_title":null,
"link_type_id":"12",
"link_href":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/DJURGARDEN"
}
]
}
],
"supportingActs":[
]
},
"media":[
],
"relatedMedia":{
"1":{
"media_id":"149466",
"width":318,
"height":187,
"file_name":"http:\/\/........net\/djurgarden-hockey_11-26-13_5_5294e4598bec3.jpg"
},
"2":{
"media_id":"149465",
"width":238,
"height":140,
"file_name":"http:\/\/........net\/djurgarden-hockey_11-26-13_6_5294e459867f5.jpg"
},
"3":{
"media_id":"149467",
"width":220,
"height":220,
"file_name":"http:\/\/........net\/djurgarden-hockey_11-26-13_7_5294e45990e1f.jpg"
},
"4":{
"media_id":"149464",
"width":134,
"height":79,
"file_name":"http:\/\/........net\/djurgarden-hockey_11-26-13_9_5294e45981552.jpg"
},
"23":{
"media_id":"149463",
"width":322,
"height":322,
"file_name":"http:\/\/........net\/djurgarden-hockey_11-26-13_24_5294e45974caa.jpg"
},
"17":{
"media_id":0,
"width":"678",
"height":"399",
"file_name":"http:\/\/dc1tv648rdvbu.....net\/...\/bundles\/aeg...\/images\/defaults\/1\/1_678_399.png"
},
"18":{
"media_id":0,
"width":"564",
"height":"564",
"file_name":"http:\/\/dc1tv648rdvbu.....net\/...\/bundles\/aeg...\/images\/defaults\/1\/1_564_564.png"
}
},
"links":[
{
"link_id":976321,
"link_title":null,
"link_type_id":"12",
"link_href":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/DJURGARDEN"
},
{
"link_id":976320,
"link_title":null,
"link_type_id":"13",
"link_href":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/difhockeyse"
}
]
}
]
}
```

Comment: your json data in not clear, please send proper json data.

Comment: it will be easier to answer if you post the Valid Json

Comment: make sure the json you are using is valid, you can test it here as well http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: My json is valid. I have updated above to a complete json feed containing 1 event. I also got answer for my problem by @user574632 below. Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use curly braces:

```
echo $event->media->{10}->width;
```

If you do not know what the properties will be called, you can iterate them in a nested loop:

```
foreach($event->media as $media){
    echo $media->width . '<br/>';
}
```

To just get the 1st property, if you do not intend to iterate them, you can use reset():

```
$first = reset($event->media);
echo $first->width;
```

Live (updated) example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/IU2wCy

Comment: Thank you very much @574632! Now that part is working for me :) 
Do you have an idea how to grab the first media key in the array if you dont know its name?

Comment: @Itsme Sure, i have updated my answer with a solution

Comment: Thank you again very much @user574632 ! Everything works just fine  now :)